# set source ipv4 address in urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

Im new in programming and now im trying to create python script that will periodically send http DELETE requests from a specific ipv4 address on machine. I don't understand what do I need to do to implement this feature.
I've read about class `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection` in urllib3 docks. As far as i understood from docks `source_address` parameter need to be passed to this class to implement this, but what do i need to do with it next? I didn't find any examples about it in docks.
Thanks for help in advance!

EDIT:
Ok, I found a solution:

```
real_create_conn = urllib3.util.connection.create_connection

def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
    source_address = ('127.0.0.1', 0)
    return real_create_conn(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=source_address)

urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = set_src_addr

import requests
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org')
```

Comment: Hi! My suggestion to get more responses and answer is to actually post the code snippet you have attempted and the corresponding errors you are seeing. This question seems very broad and open-ended.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad question, so I'll attempt to get you to the next step. I'm not familiar with that specific library, but in general, you will need to (in code/pseudo-code):

1. create the connection
   source_address = "https://the.site.apiyouwanttoconnectto.com"
   connection = urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection(source_address)
2. do something with the connection (check the docs for this)
   connection.some_delete_method('the thing you want to delete')

I hope this helps. Good luck.