# how can I keep the original reference to a function in python

Tags: python

According to [set source ipv4 address in urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442596/set-source-ipv4-address-in-urllib3), I try to use below code snippet to set the source IP in a HTTP request:

```
    def bind_ip(source_ip):
        real_create_conn = urllib3.util.connection.create_connection
   
        def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
            source_address = (source_ip, 0)
            return real_create_conn(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=source_address)
    
        urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = set_src_addr

    while url != null and ip != null:
        bind_ip(ip)
        r = requests.get(url)
```

But the server has multiple IPs, and I have to switch between them for my situation.

It works well for the first call. if calling this snippet repeatedly, things got wild.

for the second call and after, the value of "real_create_conn" is not the original implementation, but the "set_src_addr" function, which is assigned to "urllib3.util.connection.create_connection" in the later part. and it result in a "set_src_addr" chain as below picture:

[image]

I also tried to save the original "create_connection" reference in a file, but it doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can keep the original "create_connection" reference and reuse it? Or is there a workaround on it?

Comment: Seems like really ugly design imho.

Comment: @matszwecja, do you have any better suggestion on the solution?

Comment: Don't overwrite library functions like that, it will sooner or later break something in places you least expect. Use your locally defined names.

Comment: *"if calling this snippet repeatedly"* - How about simply not doing that? Do it **once**?

Comment: This question lacks information for us to reproduce the issue. Please clarify. How is this code repeated? Is this the body of another function? How is the IP address playing a dynamic role here (it is hardcoded right now)? What is the scope of the names you have here?

Comment: @KellyBundy, the link is not very stable. I check the connection before the connection.

Comment: @trincot, added the code part to make my point clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite library functions, it **will** break your code. Instead make a wrapper function and use it wherever you would use the library function.

```
import urllib3

def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
    source_address = ('192.168.0.100', 0)
    return urllib3.util.connection.create_connection(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=source_address)

import requests
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org')
```

Now if you want a differently behaving create_connection, you would use `set_src_addr` instead.

EDIT: This will **not** affect anything sent by `requests`. I'd suggest using `requests_toolbox` library for a safer way of changing its source address - specifically [SourceAddressAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#sourceaddressadapter)

Comment: Why would `requests.get` use your function just because you wrote it?

Comment: It would not, which I see as a good thing. There is a `requests` specific collection of utilities called requests_toolbelt that offers a solution for that specific problem - [SourceAddressAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#sourceaddressadapter), even suggested by one of `requests` contributor as least hacky solution here: [Binding a particular IP](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/394#issuecomment-449124824)

Comment: @matszwecja, fixed my problem with SourceAddressAdapter in requests_toolbelt lib, as you suggested. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Save the original function reference only once -- not inside your function:

```
# Save (once)
real_create_conn = urllib3.util.connection.create_connection

def bind_ip(source_ip):
    def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
        return real_create_conn(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=(source_ip, 0))

    urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = set_src_addr

while url != null and ip != null:
    bind_ip(ip)
    r = requests.get(url)

# Restore
urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = real_create_conn
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But my situation is that the source IP keeps changing, as the host has multiple links. I have to call the set_src_addr with different IP repeatedly.

Comment: But your question has a hardcoded IP address... Please update your question, so we can see what is influencing the IP address. Is it a global name? Why not a parameter? Can you clarify what exactly your function is doing to get the intended IP address?

Comment: Based on a [little test](https://tio.run/##Lck9DoAgDEDhnVPUDRbjz2bCSQgxJFJlKQ1l8fSIxrd9eXzXK9PaGgpYcF5hLrBDIiiBzqgXsynoHREB9Y83DiIfUMbAHOnQaBSXRFWjuMnDYPtzszetPQ), I don't think this'll work. Repeatedly defining the same function (even an "empty" one like mine) gives you *unequal* objects, so your `if`-condition would always be true.

Comment: Updated answer in light of the added information in the question.